# Codeigniter 4 detect and differentiate homepage from other pages

Tags: codeigniter-4

I would like to differentiate my homepage with other pages as my structure is a little different from other pages but I have no clue is it to make use of public function view(). Currently I am working on 1 page which is my profile page, the link is localhost/account/profile, in this case, how do I differentiate homepage and account page? Below are my codes :

HTML

```
<header>
<nav></nav>
// only show slider if it's homepage
<slider></slider>
</header>
```

Controller

```
class Account extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        echo view('templates/header');
        echo view('account/profile');
        echo view('templates/footer');
    }
    
    public function login()
    {
        echo view('templates/header');
        echo view('account/login');
        echo view('templates/footer');
    }
    
    
    public function register()
    {
        echo view('templates/header');
        echo view('account/register');
        echo view('templates/footer');
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------

}
```

Routes

```
$routes->match(['get', 'post'], 'account/register', 'Account::register');
$routes->match(['get', 'post'], 'account/login', 'Account::login');
$routes->match(['get', 'post'], 'account/profile', 'Account::index');
```

Please let me know if the information I needed is insufficient. Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm... Somehow it's working using this method for me. Not sure whether this is a good way though.

```
<?php 

$uri = service('uri');
if($uri->getSegment(1) == ''):
?>

<slider></slider>
<?php endif; ?>
```